# E_ACCESSDENIED (0x8007005) when calling DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat() function from DirectShowLib

Tags: c#, windows, iis, directshow, directshow.net

I have the following piece of code which is called from a IIS web service:

```
private IBaseFilter CreateFilter(Guid category, string friendlyname)
{
    object source = null;
    Guid iid = typeof(IBaseFilter).GUID;
    foreach (DsDevice device in DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(category))
        if (device.Name != null && device.Name.CompareTo(friendlyname) == 0)
        {
            device.Mon.BindToObject(null, null, ref iid, out source);
            break;
        }
    return (IBaseFilter)source;
}
```

When `DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat()`is called, the service throws the following exception:

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {62BE5D10-60EB-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86} from the IClassFactory failed
>   due to the following error: 80070005 (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
>
> at DirectShowLib.DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(Guid FilterCategory) at
>   MyVideoRenderer.CreateFilter(Guid category, String
>   friendlyname) at MyVideoRenderer.Constructor(String
>   filepath, Int32 width, Int32 height, ISampleGrabberCB BufferCB,
>   ISampleGrabberCB BufferCBSource, Rectangle sourceRect)

This has happened both in a server running Windows Server 2008 R2 and a PC running Windows 7. I do have a Windows Form which calls the same code and it works in both machines.

I don't know which category/filter caused this error, but it does require a couple of .ax/dll to be `regsvr32`-ed before usage. These dlls are inside the webservice directory, so there should be no problem with permissions.

Any tips on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: if this works running in windows I wonder if you would need to have the web application have rights / access granted and or have a user account setup to be used when running this over the web.. do you have a systems admin or someone whom administers your IIS / web server

Comment: I'm working with another dev who manages the server. But we're not sure what rights and access it'd be necessary to grant. Both registered filters and video files consumed by the application are in accessible folders. Any tips?